# How to install from a Git repo which has dependency_links pointing to another Git repo

Tags: python, pip

I use `pip install git+http://example.com/some-folder/A.git`.

The `setup.py` of project A:

```
install_requires=['B==0.1.0'],
# Dependencies
dependency_links=[
    'http://example.com/some-folder/B.git@0.1.0',
]
```

The output is:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement B==0.1.0 (from A==0.3.0) (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for B==0.1.0 (from A==0.3.0)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip ignores `dependency_links` by default.  To change this, you need to specify the `--process-dependency-links` option:

```
pip install --process-dependency-links git+http://example.com/some-folder/A.git
```